# Explain me ,binary | dont work (java)

Tags: java

I cant understand why `4 | 6` gave me answer `6`. It should be `2`.
`4 = 100` , and `6 = 110`.

```
public class ex1 {
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            int a = (4 | 6);
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you mixing OR (|) and XOR (^)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is performing a bitwise or, based on your expecting output - I believe you wanted a xor. Like,

```
int a = (4 ^ 6);
```

outputs

```
2
```